# Select Statement with Variable not working C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, oledb

I have done a bunch of Select statements with AddWithValue's and Add's but this one I can't seem to get to work.  This works fine when I put the number in instead of the @orderNum.  Tried with @orderNum and '@orderNum' when I put the '' nothing happens on button click but when I use @orderNum it says it can't find ORDERNUM in the table.  The value in the SQL table is a CHAR FOR BIT DATA so maybe that has something to do with it? Ideas?

End of my select statement:

```
WHERE POITEM.ORDNO  = @orderNum
```

Add :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@orderNum", poTextBox.Text));
```

The entire `SELECT` statement (the resulting big C# string concatenated from smaller chunks):

```
SELECT 
    CAST(POITEM.ITNBR as char(15) ccsid 37) as itemno, 
    CAST(POITEM.ITDSC as char(15) ccsid 37) as ITDSC, 
    CAST(POITEM.HOUSE as char(15) ccsid 37) as hou, 
    CAST(POITEM.REFNO as char(15) ccsid 37) as REF, 
    CAST(POITEM.STAIC as char(15) ccsid 37) as staic,
    POITEM.QTYOR,
    CAST(POITEM.UNMSR as char(15) ccsid 37) as unmsr,
    POITEM.UMCNV,
    POITEM.DKQTY,
    POITEM.STKQT,
    CAST(POITEM.JOBNO as char(15) ccsid 37) as job,
    CAST(POITEM.DPTNO as char(15) ccsid 37) as dept, 
    CAST(POITEM.VCLNB as char(15) ccsid 37) as vclnb, 
    CAST(POITEM.WHSLC as char(15) ccsid 37) as whsloc,
    POITEM.UCORQ, 
    CAST(POITEM.BLCOD as char(15) ccsid 37) as blcod, 
    CAST(POMAST.VNDNR as char(15) ccsid 37) as vendor, 
    CAST(POMAST.PSTTS as char(15) ccsid 37) as pstts,
    CAST(VENNAM.VNAME as char(15) ccsid 37) as vname, 
    CAST(OVERRD.BNAME as char(15) ccsid 37) as bname 
FROM POMAST 
LEFT OUTER JOIN POITEM ON POMAST.ORDNO = POITEM.ORDNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN OVERRD ON POMAST.ORDNO = OVERRD.ORDNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN VENNAM ON POMAST.VNDNR = VENNAM.VNDNR 
WHERE POITEM.ORDNO = @orderNum
```

Comment: Could you try setting the parameters first, then setting the `CommandText`? It usually doesn't matter, but this is an unusual case. Also, `WHERE POITEM.ORDNO  = @orderNum` is correct syntax.

Comment: I have tried it like you requested as well... it's strange I can't seem to figure out why it wouldn't work?... I didn't know if the CHAR for BIT DATA had anything to do with it?

Comment: I'm just going to go out on a limb and suggest that one side of your SQL query might be null, or you have some padding on your @orderNum param. Another thing to consider is that you need to process `poTextBox.Text` before putting it in your query, because type mismatches will prevent your code from behaving as you expect it to (or just plain cause errors).

Comment: I tried doing this instead and still get the same error... string poNum = poTextBox.Text.Trim(); the used cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@orderNum", poNum)); in case there was extra padding... still says no column found.. so strange.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("orderNum", poTextBox.Text));`

Comment: Wait, which database do you use?

Comment: @Gusman the database all the tables are under.. the code works great if I hard code the PO # like P130030 in there... just can't get the variable to work correctly for some reason.

Comment: I mean, which database you use? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? Anything else?

Comment: Ahhh SQL Server sorry misread your question.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think SQL Server has "CHAR(X) FOR BIT." You'd just use a binary or varbinary (which raises the question of how you'd map a textbox to a binary value). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512127/sql-server-datatype-for-db2-column-char-for-bit-data).

Comment: You are right sorry.. started a new job they have some SQL databases and some that are AS400.. so that would be right.  Either way the SQL select statement works fine if I hard code so why wouldn't that add string work? any clue?

Comment: Would this work?
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@orderNum", Convert.ToChar(poTextBox.Text)));

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I get the error : String must be exactly one character long .... so making some progress better than the previous error!

Comment: What value would @orderNum hold?  I guess it would be one character right? Maybe you have to trim off white space or just ensure poTextBox.Text has one character.

Comment: IT should have 7 characters... P130030 is a example PO # that would be entered in the textbox.

Comment: Can you share the entire select statement?

Comment: How about something like:  var p = new OleDbParameter("@orderNum", CorrectTypeHere, 7);
    p.Value = poTextBox.Text;  cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

Comment: You could try using ? instead of @orderNum.  Another thing to try is changing P130030 to P'130030'

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments. [edit] your instead. Also, it would help us to help you if you post not only the sql code buy also the c# code. One more thing, make sure you only tag the relevant database. It's unclear of it's MS-SQL-Server or AS400.

Answer (score 1):

You said you were able to put a number instead of `@orderNum`, so does it mean you store integer order numbers in the `CHAR FOR BIT DATA` column type or can there be order numbers like: `PO1234`?

As others have suggested you need to convert this line:

```
WHERE POITEM.ORDNO  = @orderNum
```

to

```
WHERE POITEM.ORDNO = ?
```

and then set the parameter like this if your `POITEM.ORDNO` column contains only integers with no alpha characters:

```
int poNum = 0;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(poTextBox.Text))
    Int32.TryParse(poTextBox.Text.Trim(), out poNum);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", poNum);
```

If your `POITEM.ORDNO` column contains alpha characters then just send the string instead of int as parameter:

```
string poNum = "";

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(poTextBox.Text))
    poNum = poTextBox.Text.Trim();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", poNum);
```

Try it out and let us know if it works.

Comment: This results in a System.InvalidOperationException: Command Parameter [0] data value could not be converted for easons other than sign mismatch or data overflow.

Comment: @guitarProgrammer so you have tried Int or String version? What was the poTextBox.Text value?

Comment: Figured it out... if you put $ before the "SELECT then use this for your value '{poTextBox.Text}' it works fine.. not sure why that wouldn't work calling a parameter

Comment: @guitarProgrammer it sounds strange to me, really. Would you post the whole piece of C# code as a new answer?

Answer (score 1):

don't do string concatenation to build sql, expecially with fields that are string types.

When doing an Add Parameters with value, the "@" is recognized in sql-server as a parameter name.  However, leave the "@" out of the parameter name reference.  The whole point of the parameters method is it IS a parameter and sql-server will recognize it.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@orderNum", poTextBox.Text));
```

change to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("orderNum", poTextBox.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using OleDB. OleDB does not use named paramters like `@orderNum`. It uses a `?` placeholder. So you need this:

```
WHERE POITEM.ORDNO  = ?
```

And :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = poTextBox.Text;
```

OleDb will match up which parameter to which placeholder in the query text based on the order in which you add parameters to the collection.

Or if you're talking to Sql Server, you can can use SqlClient instead of OleDb (`System.Data.SqlClient`, `SqlConnection`, and `SqlCommand` instead of `System.Data.OleDb`, `OleDbConnection`, and `OleDbCommand`). Then named paramters will work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what works... strange that the parameter didn't.  Another programmer here thought to try this and it worked!

```
OleDbCommand poSearch = new OleDbCommand("SELECT CAST(POITEM.ITNBR as char(15) ccsid 37) as itemno, CAST(POITEM.ITDSC  as char(30) ccsid 37) as ITDSC,"
      + "CAST(POITEM.HOUSE as char(15) ccsid 37) as hou,  CAST(POITEM.REFNO as char(15) ccsid 37) as REF, CAST(POITEM.STAIC as char(15) ccsid 37) as staic, "
      + "POITEM.QTYOR, CAST(POITEM.UNMSR as char(15) ccsid 37) as unmsr, POITEM.UMCNV, POITEM.DKQTY, POITEM.STKQT, CAST(POITEM.JOBNO as char(15) ccsid 37) as job,"
      + "CAST(POITEM.DPTNO as char(15) ccsid 37) as dept, CAST(POITEM.VCLNB as char(15) ccsid 37) as vclnb, CAST(POITEM.WHSLC as char(15) ccsid 37) as whsloc,"
      + "POITEM.UCORQ, CAST(POITEM.BLCOD as char(15) ccsid 37) as blcod, CAST(POMAST.VNDNR as char(30) ccsid 37) as vendor, CAST(POMAST.PSTTS as char(15) ccsid 37) as pstts,"
      + "CAST(VENNAM.VNAME as char(30) ccsid 37) as vname, CAST(OVERRD.BNAME as char(15) ccsid 37) as bname  FROM POMAST LEFT OUTER JOIN POITEM ON POMAST.ORDNO = POITEM.ORDNO "
      + $"LEFT OUTER JOIN OVERRD ON POMAST.ORDNO = OVERRD.ORDNO LEFT OUTER JOIN VENNAM ON POMAST.VNDNR = VENNAM.VNDNR  WHERE POITEM.ORDNO  = '{poTextBox.Text}'", cn);
```

Comment: AAhhhgggg... SQL-INJECTION EXPOSURE

Comment: Don't do this. It's vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, @DRapp don't you find the `$` sign at the beginning of the last line to be strange? I doubt it will ever compile. AFAIK only `@` is allowed before strings in C#.

Comment: @andrew recent versions of c# use it to do string interpolation

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn ok, thanks for the note, will look up this in the docs.